# My single.php page does not show the related data to the post which is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I have a post for my site's logo and I have inserted its thumbnail in my header.php using the code below and it works fine:

```
<div id="logo">
    <?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1&cat=12');

    while ($my_query->have_posts()):
    $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

      <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'site-logo'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Beside this I have a single.php file where I show the details of a post using Advanced Custom Fields plugin's codes and my problem is when I click on a post and I get redirected to single.php instead of seeing its thumbnail and details I see the site's logo and the details are empty.

This happened right after I added my logo as a post and used that post's thumbnail. Before that my single.php page was functioning very well.

How can I fix this without removing the logo? (Or if this problem is because of inserting logo this way recommend me a better way.)

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add your logo as a single image using HTML's <img> tag and This php code in src attribute of img tag: `<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/` ?

Comment: thanks for your offer but I want to make my site's admin able to change the logo whenever he/she wants. By the way I cannot understand why should adding the code I mentioned in the question to the header.php affect the way single.php looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266493/my-single-php-page-does-not-show-the-related-data-to-the-post-which-is-clicked). Thanks to **WebElaine**. All I need to do
>   is:

This probably has to do with the custom query - it's preventing other queries from working properly.

Setting a logo as a post seems an odd approach. Media attachments are already posts in and of themselves. Additionally, WP has a nice logo feature - [`custom-logo`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266493/my-single-php-page-does-not-show-the-related-data-to-the-post-which-is-clicked). I would add the logo that way and then just call the theme mod for the logo. That way you're not adding an extra query that throws off other queries.

In theme's functions.php:

```
<?php add_theme_support('custom-logo'); ?>
```

In theme's header.php:

```
<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
```